# Gaming macros on ubuntu

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, games, xbindkeys

I've been able to run League of Legends on wine, and now i'm trying to associate macros to my mouse buttons. I've used xbindkeys+xte to simulate keystrokes. For example:

```
# Press mouse button 1, will simulate q and w keys from keyboard.
"xte 'sleep 0.2' 'key q' 'sleep 0.2' 'sleep w'"
m:0x10 + c:10
Mod2 + 1
```

**But this approach has some problems:**

- Sleep is accumulative. So, if you smash buttons, the macro will stuck for a while.
- You must use sleep. Otherwise, `xbindkeys` won't recognize xte actions.
- This means macros are always laggy and will sometimes fail.

So, in practice, this is not suitable for gaming. Is there a workaround or alternative?